# Cisco ACL to block connections with ICMP or RST

Tags: cisco, acl

The Cisco "deny" ACL seems to quietly drop TCP/IP packets. Is it possible for it to send either ICMP responses or TCP RST's in response to a denied request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: no. Cisco IP Access Lists can only "permit" or "deny" (drop) packets.

Edit: I stand corrected. Configuring [IP Unreachables](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/ipapp/command/reference/iap_i2.html#wp1088079) on the interface results in an ICMP-unreachable message when the packet is dropped.

```
interface FastEthernet0/1
 ip address 10.1.1.2 255.255.255.0
 ip access-group 101 in
 ip unreachables
end
```

Comment: Take care with the *ip unreachables* as this will increase CPU utilization.  ACLs are processed in hardware, but unreachable messages are CPU processed.  See Cisco docs like [this one](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/access-lists/13608-21.html#anc73) for more information.

Comment: FYI Cisco [rate limits icmp unreachables](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/12_2sb/feature/guide/sbipicmp.html) by default in ios